# Reciprocals with repeating part 18 digits long in binary, and the Leech lattice

Tags: group-theory, elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic, integer-lattices

We calculate $\displaystyle \frac{1}{1387} = 0.\overline{000000010111101000}_2$. Take the repeating part as a bitstring and rotate two steps to the right to obtain $000000000101111010$ with binary complement $101111111111010000_2 = 196560$.

The Leech lattice has kissing number $196560$.

> Why should we expect a connection between the binary expansion of $\displaystyle\frac{1}{19\times73}$ and the kissing number of the Leech lattice?

The question asks for a mere hint simply because I see no reason why one could suspect that the orbit of $2$ mod $1387$ and the kissing number of a lattice should have anything to do with each other. In particular, one is a quantity, and the other is a sequence, that just happen to be represented by the same bitstring.

The answer that this is coincidental is deeply unsatisfying due to the following observation.

We  examine other reciprocals that expand to an $18$-digit repeating part. Let $f(n)$ be the function taking $n$ to the the repeating part of $\displaystyle\frac{1}{n}$ in binary and denote by $\to^n$ the right-shift operation performed $n$ times. Then the following is $f$ evaluated on every integer $n$ where $2$ has order $18$ mod $n$ (that I found with sage), rotated to the closest number to $2^{16} \times 3 = 196608$ (we count rotations that start with $0$ as the binary complement).
$$\begin{align}
f(19 = 19) \to^2 &= 193158 = 2^{16}\times3 - 3450\\
f(27 = 3^3) \to^2 &= 194180  = 2^{16}\times3 - 2428\\
f(57 = 3^19) \to^2 &= 197757  = 2^{16}\times3 + 1149\\
f(133 = 7^119) \to^2 &= 197100  = 2^{16}\times3 + 492\\
f(171 = 3^219) \to^2 &= 196224 = 2^{16}\times3 - 384\\
f(189 = 3^37) \to^2 &= 196954 = 2^{16}\times3 + 346\\
f(219 = 3^173) \to^2 &=  196308 = 2^{16}\times3 - 300\\
f(399 = 3^17^119) \to^2 &=  196443 = 2^{16}\times3 - 165\\
f(513 = 3^319) \to^2 &=  196753 = 2^{16}\times3 + 145\\
f(657 = 3^273) \to^2 &=  196707 = 2^{16}\times3 + 99\\
f(1197 = 3^27^119) \to^2 &=  196662 = 2^{16}\times3 + 54\\
f(1387 = 19^173) \to^2 &=  196560 = 2^{16}\times3 - 48\\
f(1533 = 3^17^173) \to^2 &=  196650 = 2^{16}\times3 + 42\\
f(1971 = 3^373) \to^2 &=  196574 = 2^{16}\times3 - 34\\
f(3591 = 3^37^119) \to^2 &=  196589 = 2^{16}\times3 - 19\\
f(4161 = 3^119^173) \to^2 &=  196623 = 2^{16}\times3 + 16\\
f(4599 = 3^27^173) \to^2 &=  196593 = 2^{16}\times3 - 15\\
f(9709 = 7^119^173) \to^2 &=  196614 = 2^{16}\times3 + 6\\
f(12483 = 3^219^173^1) \to^2 &=  196602 = 2^{16}\times3 - 6\\
f(13797 = 3^37^173) \to^2 &=  196612 = 2^{16}\times3 + 4\\
f(29127 = 3^17^119^173) \to^2 &=  196605 = 2^{16}\times3 - 3\\
f(37449 = 3^319^173) \to^2 &=  196609 = 2^{16}\times3 + 1\\
f(87381 = 3^27^119^173) \to^2 &=  196608 = 2^{16}\times 3 \\
f(262143 = 3^37^119^173) \to^2 &=  196607 = 2^{16}\times3 - 1\\
\end{align}$$

Incidentally, $$f(11) \to^2 = 744$$

Comment: The merit of your question basically comes down to if 1387 is special in some way. Otherwise this is rather arbitrary. Look at it this way, every natural number corresponds to a repeating part of some $2$-adic expansion. For 196560 it just happens to be 1387. So unless there is something special about 1387, the connection is vapid. Furthermore, what justifies reversing the bits half-way though? That step seems especially arbitrary. I don't mean to discourage you by the way, as the $2$-adics and Leech lattice are coincidentally two of my favorite subjects.

Comment: @Graviton I am rather surprised by your judgment that these steps are arbitrary. The value 196560 happens in the middle of a seemingly convergent series that starts as early as 19, and also 11 corresponds to 744 it seems to me unwise to not look deeper into this. The step of reversing the bitstring comes from the intuition that p-adic numbers "grow" in reverse to real numbers (they go left while real numbers go right). I understand that every odd reciprocal corresponds to some number. My motivation is that the pattern around 196560 appears as early as in 1/19.

Comment: @Graviton Another possible motivation is the following. The series I gave was found by filtering by bitstring length of exactly 18. This means that the possible range for the resulting bitstrings is 131071 < n < 262143 (because leading zeroes are treated as marking the complement). If there were no structure we'd expect to find randomly distributed values inside this range, but instead we find the above sequence that covers a far narrower range, seems to converge, has 24 terms (up to my computation's precision) and goes through the Leech lattice's kissing number.

Comment: Thank you for adding some clarity. I will have a deeper look.

Comment: How did you obtain $744$ from $1/11$? Loosely, the repeating part of $-1/n$ is given by the formula $(2^{\phi(n)}-1)/n$ with a period length of $\phi(n)$. For $n=11$ we have repeating part $1011101_2$ with a period of $10$, therefore $$-1/11 = \dots 0001011101_2,$$ hence taking the compliment we find $$1/11=\dots 1110100010.1\dots_2.$$ Since $0.1\dots=1$, we can remove the fractional part, but this breaks the pattern in the right-most repetition, thus $$1/11=(\dots1110100010)1110100011_2.$$ Reversing the repeating part, and treating it as an expansion yields $0100010111_2=279_{10}$, not $744$?

Comment: Even if we retroactively offset the repeating part after our change, we get $$1/11=(\dots0111010001)1_2,$$ which again, reversing the bits yields $1000101110_2=558$, and not $744$?

Comment: Oh I see, you have offset the repeating part to $$1/11=(\dots0001011101)00011.$$ I know I've already aggressively used the term "arbitrary" but... this is a strange place to start the repeating part, especially when declaring the significance to $744$.

Comment: Thank you for pointing this out. There indeed seems to be an error, or perhaps oversight in my program where the repeating part isn't properly indexed, leading to my results being non-canonical. Before posting here, I double-checked with Mathematica for a good number of expansions, but found no value in disagreement with my code. Nevertheless I apologize for this oversight. I agree that given this it is very difficult to justify delving deeper into this, so I will clean up my code and see if the pattern remains after doing so.

Comment: Not to worry, these small mistakes happen. I hope the revised code still produces interesting results!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/146123/discussion-between-l-e-and-graviton).

Comment: @Graviton Lightly reviewing my code I'm less certain that there is an error leading to the r.p. being improperly indexed. But more urgently, I've found the reason I obtained 744 for 1/11 whereas you didn't. As per your calculation, the corresponding bitstring is 0100010111. Because this has a leading zero, I instead consider the binary complement 1011101000, which does represent 744. My motivation for this is that the process should reflect the length of the bitstring while maintaining the content. Out of the two ways to do this (the other being adding a leading 1), this felt less arbitrary.

Comment: Still I understand that things are quite messy at the moment and my process isn't well documented enough to ask others to explain what is going on. I will update the question if I manage to formalize it well enough to remove this ambiguity.